# How can I find all the cronjobs on my system?

Tags: cron

I have a rogue cron job that runs every 10 minutes on a Centos system.

How do I find all the jobs that are performed?

Comment: How do you know it's a cron job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question on StackOverflow ([How do I list all cron jobs for all users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134906/how-do-i-list-all-cron-jobs-for-all-users)).  The short version is that you could run the following (@Kyle Burton's answer on that question):

`for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done`

There is also a more indepth script that you could copy and run on that post.

Comment: thats pretty cool .

Comment: jini: Be aware that this is not necessarily going to find your rogue job. It will only work if your rogue job is in a crontab of a current user and not in /etc/crontab or /etc/cron.daily/* etc or a crontab of a deleted user.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you're root, just check the directory `/var/spool/cron/tabs`. In there should be a complete list of all *user* crons. There are also crons that run out of the `/etc/cron*` directories. Just run:

```
# ls -l /etc/cron*
# ls -l /var/spool/cron/tabs/
```

To see them all.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
for crontab in `ls /etc/cron.*/* /var/spool/cron/* /etc/crontab`
do
    echo $crontab
    cat $crontab
done
```

And remember to check the log file /var/log/cron or similar which will list everything that has been run by cron.